# Unable to get Mediawiki .htaccess Short URL to work:

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, mediawiki

I have mediawiki set up like this:

```
mysite.com/w/
```

I am trying to add the Short URL method like it suggested in the manual here:

```
https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Short_URL/Apache
```

I used the redwerks tool to generate the .htaccess rewriting rules:

```
http://shorturls.redwerks.org/
```

Although I am on VPS with root access, I find changing the Apache config and Nginx config to be too complicated and way over my head. So I decided to go with the htaccess method and I couldnt get it to work completely. This is what I added the .htaccess file in the root path:

```
RewriteRule ^/?wiki(/.*)?$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/w/index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^/?$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/w/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?w/images/thumb/[0-9a-f]/[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)px-.*$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/w/thumb.php?f=$1&width=$2 [L,QSA,B]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?w/images/thumb/archive/[0-9a-f]/[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)px-.*$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/w/thumb.php?f=$1&width=$2&archived=1 [L,QSA,B]
```

And I Added these to the LocalSettings.php

```
## The URL base path to the directory containing the wiki;
## defaults for all runtime URL paths are based off of this.
## For more information on customizing the URLs please see:
## http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Short_URL
$wgScriptPath = "/w";
$wgScriptExtension = ".php";
$wgArticlePath = "/wiki/$1";
```

AND

```
## To enable image uploads, make sure the 'images' directory
## is writable, then set this to true:
$wgEnableUploads  = true;
```

After the above, the redirection sort of works. Meaning, if I go to mysite.com/w/index.php/Page_Title, it redirects to mysite.com/wiki/Page_Title. But the following doesnt work:

1) When I type in mysite.com/wiki, it doesnt find the page and doesnt automatically goes to Main Page like it used to do when I typed mysite.com/w/. So do I need to add a separate Rewrite rule for this?

2) I am also receiving a page not found and its creating a new article page when the url looks like: mysite.com/wiki/index.php. In this case, it is trying to create a index.php article instead of directing me to Main Page.

3) Even when the above rule is on, when I got to pages other than the main article page, such as edit a page or view history, etc.. it still shows the url as mysite.com/w/index.php?title=XYZ&action=edit. Why doesnt it convert all urls to wiki?

4) If a url has a ?title added to it, it doesnt get redirected to wiki. For example, this page mysite.com/w/index.php?title=Main Page, does not become mysite.com/wiki/Main_Page

After seeing the above, now I am thinking if its better to have my wiki installation to mysite.com/wiki/ folder instead of 'w' folder. Infact thats how I had it first but later changed it when I trying to implement the Short URL method since the MW Manual suggests against it. So I need some guidance on how to resolve this please...

These are just some of the issues I've noticed so far. So basically rewrite rule doesnt completely rewrite all the pages. It only rewriting the main article page url by removing the index.php/ from the url and changing w to wiki. But other urls types are still the same and are not rewritten. When I checked the mediawiki website, all of their urls are rewritten to /wiki/ without the index.php even when editing page, etc.. How can I get the same results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay after further searching on the net, this is what I found.

> Even when the above rule is on, when I got to pages other than the
>   main article page, such as edit a page or view history, etc.. it still
>   shows the url as mysite.com/w/index.php?title=XYZ&action=edit. Why
>   doesnt it convert all urls to wiki?

This is how its supposed to work. So this means the Main pages, Namespace pages and Special Pages will have this short url while the other pages like edit page, history, etc.. will still show w/index.php/......

> If a url has a ?title added to it, it doesnt get redirected to wiki.
>   For example, this page mysite.com/w/index.php?title=Main Page, does
>   not become mysite.com/wiki/Main_Page

It only rewrites the article urls and I should never include ?title=$1 or something like it in the rewrite. Including a query will cause MediaWiki's built in handling to be overridden and will create bugs on your wiki due to the fact that Apache's query rewrites are broken. The goal here is to alias paths to /index.php and then let MediaWiki itself take care of parsing and routing the url, based on the configuration in LocalSettings.php.

> So basically rewrite rule doesnt completely rewrite all the pages. It
>   only rewriting the main article page url by removing the index.php/
>   from the url and changing w to wiki. But other urls types are still
>   the same and are not rewritten.

I later found out that thats how it is supposed to work.

I am yet to find an answer for 1 and 2. I think I need to add a separate redirect rule for that. I have asked a separate question to find the htaccess rewrite rule for that: [How to redirect Mediawiki Short URL with no title to Main Page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18843356/how-to-redirect-mediawiki-short-url-with-no-title-to-main-page)

I will update this topic once I have the answer for those..

**UPDATE:**

For no: 1, I just need to move the rewrite rule to the top before other rewrite rules and it worked after that. More info: [How to redirect Mediawiki Short URL with no title to Main Page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18843356/how-to-redirect-mediawiki-short-url-with-no-title-to-main-page/18882999#18882999)

For no: 2: wiki/index.php will not be redirected to wiki/Main_Page since it will look at index.php as a new article. It will only redirect w/index.php to /wiki/Main_Page